# Php + mysql - как оно вообще работает?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Есть скрипт, в котором выполняются определённые действия с полями в базе данных:

1. Извлечь из таблицы A данные для строки B и поля C - значение D=0.
2. Какое-то время что-то считать.
3. new_D=D+1.
4. Апдейт в таблицу А, данные для строки B и поля C - значение new_D.

Если одновременно этот скрипт вызывают 10 раз, запросы в MySQl станут в очередь или будут на выполнении этапа 2 выполняться этапы 1 и 4 другими параллельными вызовами?

Не получиться так, что 10 паралельных вызовов приведут к тому, что в итоге в таблице будет D=1, а не 10?

Если нет строго формируемой очереди для выполнения всех запросов скрипта, то дайте инфу, как правильно работать с этим делом.

Наткнулся на использование LOCK TABLES, и появилась мысль, что скрипт кривой...

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Если вам не надо значение `D` высчитывать, то, может быть, стоит делать просто:

    UPDATE A SET C = C + 1 WHERE B = ...

Тогда после каждого апдейта значение будет увеличиваться на единицу и не важно, в каком порядке придут запросы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне надо так как написал, с задержкой между 1 и 4.

Comment: Так кто мешает обновлять потом? В чем проблема-то?

Такой подход может вызвать трудности, если надо обновлять основываясь на текущих данных, но если вам надо просто увеличить счетчик (что показано в примере), так и увеличивайте его.

Другой вариант блокирования - `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` - вроде как блокирует только нужные строки, а с остальными строками можно продолжать работать (что лучше полного блокирования через `LOCK TABLES`)

Comment: Надо обновлять на текущих и постоянно меняющихся данных, а не просто счётчик - в примере сделал +1 для простоты примера.

Ответьте на вопрос, если не сложно:
В начале скрипта взяли из таблицы значение (SELECT) - пауза рандом 3-5 сек - в конце скрипта увеличили на 1 (UPDATE var='$new_var'). Если параллельно 10 раз вызову скрипт - в таблице будет значение 1 или 10?

Comment: Здесь работает принцип "кто последний тот и папа", т.е. в таблице будет от 1 до 10. Поэтому вам надо следить за тем, кто будет последним. Используйте `...FOR UPDATE` - должно помочь, либо придумайте другой подход. Главное, чтобы остальные запросы ждали своей очереди.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую пересобрать всё на FOR UPDATE. А если был SELECT FOR UPDATE а в конце не было UPDATE для этой таблицы - доступ к ней будет заблочен или разлочится по завершению скрипта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Транзакции ?

Comment: Перечитал транзакции и select foe update - всё кривое какоето, где то запираются и не отпираются таблицы, где-то, при сложных запросах ещё какие-то неожиданности вылазят, с которыми потом возиться и разбираться надо. Решил сделать опорную таблицу с одним значением - статус выполнения скрипта. 
Запираю в начале файла повторный вызов этого файла через эту таблицу, при завершении отпираю. Если 50 человек ломятся в один файл - ставятся в псевдоочредь (ожидание 1 сек и скрипт заново проверяет запирающую таблицу).
 
Может решение и деревянное, но нового геморроя с транзакциями и for update избежал.

Comment: Ох, и вот так каждый пытается вылепить собственный велосипед :)

Comment: @Василий Панферов

> при сложных запросах ещё какие-то неожиданности вылазят, с которыми потом возиться и разбираться надо.

Программирование оно такое